# Client side validation in MVC3 partial view half working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I'm having problems with client side validation on our account creation form in MVC3.  I am using data annotations on the model and the view is a partial view.  Only two of the fields are being validated when I run it in a partial view.  When I put the code in a regular view all of the fields are being validated.

After searching this seems to be a common problem but this case seems different because it is "half working", meaning that I am sure the .js libs are loaded and at least sort of working.  I am not loading anything with Ajax which seems to cause problems.  I'm using jquery 1.5.1 and jquery.validate 1.8.0 which are IIRC what came with the install of MVC3.

Has anyone seen/solved this sort of problem?

Here is my view:

```
<%: Html.Hidden("Bounce", Model.Bounce)%>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="FirstName">First Name</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("FirstName", Model.FirstName)%><br />
    <%=Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName")%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="MiddleName">Middle Name</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("MiddleName", Model.MiddleName)%><br />
    <%=Html.ValidationMessage("MiddleName")%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="LastName">Last Name</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("LastName", Model.LastName)%><br />
    <%=Html.ValidationMessage("LastName")%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="Email">Email</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("Email", Model.Email)%><br />
    <%=Html.ValidationMessage("Email")%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="Password1">Password</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.Password("Password1",Model.Password1)%><br />
    <%=Html.ValidationMessage("Password1")%>
</div>

<div class="editor-label"><label for="Password2">Confirm Password</label></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.Password("Password2",Model.Password2)%><br />
    <%=Html.ValidationMessage("Password2")%>
</div>

<div class="form-controls"><input type="submit" value="Create Account" /></div>
```

The view is being rendered with

`<% Html.RenderPartial("create", new CustomerCreationRequest()); %>`

This is the Model

```
public class CustomerCreationRequest
{


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password1 { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password1", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation do not match.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password confirmation is required")]
    public string Password2 { get; set; }

    public string Bounce { get; set; } //bounce
}
```

The two fields that work correctly are the Password1 and Password2 fields.  Both validation rules work aswell (i.e. the Require and Compare).  All other fields are not being validated and will allow the form to be submitted when blank.

**Update**

When looking at the generated markup it appears the data-val-required field is not present on the first 4 normal input fields but does appear on the last 2 password fields (the ones that work).

**Update 2**

After the form is submitted and rejected by the server the data-val-required field *does* appear and all of the inputs work correctly and are validating.  It is only on the initial load that they are only appearing on the password fields.

Comment: This may not be the problem but still r u using unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Yes I have <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> in the web.config

Comment: I hope you have included the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js library as well?

Comment: Yes.  I am including jquery.min, jquery.validate.min and validate.unobtrusive.min

Comment: Did you check the value of this.ModelState.IsValid inside your action method? If it's true, you know the problem is not JavaScript. If it is false, you know it is.

Comment: Yes the ModelState.IsValid is false on the server side.  When I submit the form with required fields blank, the server side validation will kick in correctly with all of the Html.ValidationMessage and Html.ValidationSummary calls showing the problems and red outlines around the inputs.  I am pretty certain it's the client validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the processof updating the code to MVC and using strongly typed views and from previous versions there was a block of code in the controller that was writing out these named fields to ViewData.  e.g.

```
        ViewData["loginError"] = "";
        ViewData["createError"] = "";
        ViewData["firstName"] = "";
        ViewData["middleName"] = "";
        ViewData["lastName"] = "";
        ViewData["email"] = "";
```

When I removed these everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is mainly due to the library mismatch(possibly the jquery validation library). When I created a fresh MVC 3 project I don't see a version no. in the jquery validation library.

Please update the libraries to latest using nuget.

PM> Install-Package jQuery

PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation

PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive

Comment: I updated the jquery in nuget and I'm still seeing the same problem.  I am now on jquery 1.7.2 jquery.validate 1.9.0 (the version number is in the header of the source file).  I did not see a version number on the validate.unobtrusive file.  In the package manager log it says it installed 2.0.20505.0